# SQL Server General Pivoting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have this SQL table called **Comments** with 2 columns: NCC_CLTID and NCC_CTYPE

The table has the following information

```
NCC_CLTID   NCC_CTYPE
TEST1         A 
TEST1         A 
TEST1         C
TEST1         E
TEST1         E
TEST1         E 
TEST1         E
TEST2         A
TEST2         B
TEST2         B
TEST2         C
```

I want a pivot table that looks like the following:

```
NCC_CLTID TYPE1 TYPE2 TYPE3 TYPE4 TYPE5 TYPE6 TYPE7 TYPE8 ... TYPE20
TEST1       A    A      C     E    E      E     E    NULL      NULL
TEST2       A    B      B     C    NULL   NULL  NULL  NULL      NULL
```

How can I achieve this? I can't see a way to make this work for some reason

Comment: What wrong with the `PIVOT` operator then? Or, alternatively, the less restrictive method, conditional aggregation.

Comment: I can't figure out a way to do the query. Do you know how it can be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far, why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have known or maximum number of `TYPE`s, you can use row_number() to determine the column

**Example**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select [NCC_CLTID]
              ,[NCC_CTYPE]
              ,Item = concat('Type',row_number() over (partition by [NCC_CLTID] order by [NCC_CTYPE]) )
        from YourTable
      ) src
 Pivot (max([NCC_CTYPE]) for Item in ([Type1],[Type2],[Type3],[Type4],[Type5],
                                      [Type6],[Type7],[Type8],[Type9],[Type10],
                                      [Type11],[Type12],[Type13],[Type14],[Type15],
                                      [Type16],[Type17],[Type18],[Type19],[Type20]
                                     ) ) pvt
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! This is a correct answer. Thank you so much. Just a question, why did we use max for aggregate?

Comment: @PedroEmilioVélez Always happy to help.   I used MAX as a default for a string.  You could have used MIN, however, SUM or other aggregations would not make sense for non-numerics.   Pivots require an aggregation

Comment: Done! Thank you so much John. Just for my last question: What are the limitations on the amount of columns? What if I want to add 50 columns for the Types, how can I upgrade this procedure?

Comment: @PedroEmilioVélez 50 columns would not be a problem.   Just add to the ITEM IN ( ...  ,[Type21],[Type22], ...  ,[Type50])    Be sure to bracket [] the column names and be sure they are separated by a comma.

Comment: @PedroEmilioVélez Just to be clear.  SQL Server has a maximum number of columns of 1,024.